# Two connex components with different orientations - The surface cannot be orientable!

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, parametrization, orientation

I need to prove that if $S $ is a surface covered by two coordinate neighborhood $V,U $ s.t. $V\cap U $ has two connex and the jacobian of coordinate change is positive in once and negative in other, so $S $ is not orientable.

I cannot see how could I prove this. I appreciate some clue to beginning.

Thanks in advance.

=====

PS.: 1) I do not know if in English this is not used. I mean "connex components" in sense of connex pieces disconnected.

2) This is the question 1 of section 2.6 from Manfredo do Carmo's book: Differential geometry of curves and surfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $S$ was orientable, $S$ would have an atlas $\mathcal T = (T_j, \varphi_j)$ where the Jacobians of all the transition functions are positive.

Denote $C_1,C_2$ the two connected components of $U \cap V$ and take $u_i \in T_i \cap C_i$ for $i \in \{1,2\}$. As $S$ is path connected, consider a path $f$ joining $u_1$ to $u_2$. A chain of charts of $\mathcal T$ covering $f$ would have all positive transition functions. A contradiction with the hypothesis regarding the $U,V$ atlas.

Comment: Hi. I am sorry, I think I did not explain well. I mean "connex components" in sense of two conex parts of the intersection, by they are not conectted. I do not know if in English this is not used... I mean "connex components" in sense of connex pieces disconnected. Could you understand? Many thanks.

Comment: I was reading once again your answer and maybe I misunderstood you. I think your answer is very good. Sorry! Thank you.